# Getting controls of forms inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on an AngularJS app and created two forms inside a directive. I want to reset both form's $submitted by $setSubmitted(false), however, the problem is that I cannot get two controls at the same time inside the directive controller.

Referred to this solution [How to handle multiple forms present in a single page using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546068/how-to-handle-multiple-forms-present-in-a-single-page-using-angularjs/43563103#43563103). However, the solution is for a controller, not for a directive.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('multiForms', multiForms);

  function multiForms() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
      },
      controller: function ($scope) {

        $scope.functions = {
            submit1: submit1,
            submit2: submit2,
            resetForms: resetForms
        };

        function resetForms() {
            $scope.form1.$setSubmitted(false);
            $scope.form2.$setSubmitted(false);
        }

      },
      replace: false,
      templateUrl: 'pathToTheHtml.html'
    }
  }

})();
```

```
<div>
    <form name="form1" ng-submit="functions.submit1()">
        <ng-form name="form1">
            <input type="text" ng-model="text1">
            <button type="submit">Submit1</button>
        </ng-form>
    </form>
    <form name="form-2" ng-submit="functions.submit2()">
            <ng-form name="form2">
                <input type="text" ng-model="text2">
                <button type="submit">Submit2</button>
            </ng-form>        
    </form>
    <button ng-click="functions.resetForms()"></button>
</div>
```

The expected results is to set $submitted value to false for both form1 and form2. The actual result is both $scope.form1 and $scope.form2 are undefined.

Comment: where is your _multi-forms_ element?

Comment: In the second part of the code (HTML). I put two forms, form1 and form2.

Comment: how are you binding your forms with your directive?

Comment: Can you create a code pen demo of your issue? It would really help in debugging.

Comment: I actually spent more time and was able to figure it out. Thanks so much for the replies! I was able to bind forms and the directive by using 'vm'.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around and this actually worked. I added vm and binded with the view.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('multiForms', multiForms);

  function multiForms() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
      },
      controller: function ($scope) {

        const vm = this;

        vm.functions = {
            submit1: submit1,
            submit2: submit2,
            resetForms: resetForms
        };

        function resetForms() {
            vm.form1.$setPristine();
            vm.form2.$setPristine();
        }

      },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true,
      replace: false,
      templateUrl: 'pathToTheHtml.html'
    }
  }

})();
```

```
<div>
    <form name="vm.form1" ng-submit="vm.functions.submit1()">
        <ng-form name="form1">
            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.data.text1">
            <button type="submit">Submit1</button>
        </ng-form>
    </form>
    <form name="vm.form-2" ng-submit="vm.functions.submit2()">
            <ng-form name="form2">
                <input type="text" ng-model="vm.data.text2">
                <button type="submit">Submit2</button>
            </ng-form>        
    </form>
    <button ng-click="vm.functions.resetForms()"></button>
</div>
```